# Issue running foreach loop inside a table

Tags: php, loops, foreach

This is the code that am using to run the foreach loop that will dynamically render * on the page. The problem is in this portion of the code. Please guide me to the right direction.

The * is echo on the top of the page, it should echo inside the td as per code.
[image: Output]

**This is the current code am working with.**

```
if( in_array($date, $dateKeyStack) ){
$calendar .= "<td class='day' rel='$date'><div class='current-day'>$currentDay</div><div class='current-events'>
  <div class=\"have-events\">"; ?>
    <?php
      foreach($array_count_values as $key => $value){
        if( $key == $date ){
          $events_show_boxes = "*";
          echo $events_show_boxes;
        }
      }
    ?><?php "
  </div>
</td>";
} else if($currentDayRel == $today_date ){
    $calendar .= "<td class='day its-today' rel='$date'><div class='current-day'>$currentDay</div><div class='current-events'>&nbsp;</div></td>";
} else {
    $calendar .= "<td class='day' rel='$date'><div class='current-day'>$currentDay</div><div class='current-events'>&nbsp;</div></td>";
}
```

Comment: *CSS* for the `<div>`, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're echoing the asterisk but building the table to a variable. Store the asteriks in the calendar variable.

```
$calendar .= "<td class='day' rel='$date'><div class='current-day'>$currentDay</div><div class='current-events'>
  <div class=\"have-events\">"; ?>
    <?php
      foreach($array_count_values as $key => $value){
        if( $key == $date ){
          $events_show_boxes = "*";
          echo $events_show_boxes;
        }
      }
    ?>
```

or don't echo and use that variable elsewhere...

Answer (score 1):

```
if( in_array($date, $dateKeyStack) ){
$calendar .= "<td class='day' rel='$date'><div class='current-day'>$currentDay</div><div class='current-events'>
  <div class=\"have-events\">"; ?>
    <?php
      foreach($array_count_values as $key => $value){
        if( $key == $date ){
          $events_show_boxes = "*";
          $calendar.=$events_show_boxes;
        }
      }
    ?><?php $calendar.="
  </div>
</td>";
}
echo $calendar
```

Build $events_show_boxes into the calendar variable